# PartialView rendering not rendering on home page, throwing HttpExceptionn

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm learning MVC and I'm trying to render a Partialview on Home Page.
I'm getting following error :

> "HttpException"

My very simple model is as follows:

```
public class simpleModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowNames()
{
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();               
    return PartialView(db.SimpleModels.ToList());
}
```

partial view:

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.simpleModel>
@if (Model != null)
{
   <ul>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <li>@item.Name</li>
      }
</ul>
}
```

Home page where I want my partial view to render is

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <p>To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit </p>
    </section>
}
@{
    Html.RenderAction("ShowNames", "Simple");
}
```

Comment: You're passing down a collection, `List` when the View has an instance  model `MvcApplication1.Models.simpleModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ShowNames()` method returns a collection of `simpleModel` items to the view (as in `db.SimpleModels.ToList()`) but your partial declares the model as a single `simpleModel` onject. That would throw and exception, as would your attempt to iterate a single object using the `foreach` loop.

Change the partial view model declaration to

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.simpleModel>
```

but since `<li>name</li>` would just return the text "name" (or assuming its actually `<li>@name</li>` then it would return the text "MvcApplication1.Models.simpleModel" unless you have overridden the `ToString()` method of `simpleModel`), so you need to access a property of the object

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in model)
    {
        <li>@item.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I tried this, but still the result is same exception.

Comment: My answer fixes 2 exceptions that your code would have thrown. If you still have exceptions, its not because of the code you have shown - I have already tested it (manually adding a few `simpleModel` objects to the collection) and it works fine. You need to show the stack trace (and remove that image - its of no help at all)

Comment: You should also put a break point on the first line of the partial view to help narrow down the cause of the error.

Comment: I tried to put breakpoint in partial view. but its not able to reach their. Its throwing exception on index page itself . at @{
                Html.RenderAction("ShowNames", "Simple");
             }

Comment: What did you do to solve the problem? Did you get the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Your model might be null i.e its not having any data.
So, you should put a check before the foreachloop

@model List

```
@if(model != null)
{
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in model)
    {
        <li>@item.Name</li>
   }
</ul>
}
```

Comment: Model has 3 items, it not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [ChildActionOnly] attribute to your ShowNames method.